# Receiving Error "User login alias should not be null" When Attempting to Log User In On Android Using AWS Cognito User Pools

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I've set up a user pool for a mobile application. The sign up process works as expected, however, attempting to log in the user in results in the following Exception:

> User login alias should not be null (Service:
>   AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   InvalidParameterException; Request ID: xxx....)
>
> This error is being produced during the sign in attempt, called via:
>   CognitoUserPool.getUser(username).getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler);

To provide a fuller snippet of the code, when the user clicks the login button, a function containing the following code is run:

```
AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler = new AuthenticationHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession userSession) {
            Util.showMessage(mContext, "User Successfully Signed In. Session JWT Token: " + userSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken());
            btnLogin.setProgress(100);
        }

        @Override
        public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String UserId) {
            AuthenticationDetails authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(UserId, edtPassword.getText().toString().trim(), null);
            authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails);
            authenticationContinuation.continueTask();
        }

        @Override
        public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation continuation) {
            Util.showMessage(mContext, "MFA Code is Required");
            // Set Up MFA Process
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, exception.toString());
            Snackbar.make(edtUsername, exception.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            btnLogin.setProgress(-1);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    setUpLoginClick();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    };

    AWS.userPool(mContext).getUser(edtUsername.getText().toString()).getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler);
```

AWS.userPool(Context ctx) is a utility function that i wrote to quickly retrieve the configured UserPool object.

Can anyone shed some light on why this might be happening? I can't find discussion or documentation of this error anywhere.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of your sign in code? I'd guess you're providing neither a username or an alias, but that's based on little.

Comment: I've amended the code @JeffBailey to show the sign in code. I'm proving the username in the getUser() method call to the UserPool object.